# How to set cookies from appsync lambda resolver

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, aws-lambda, aws-appsync

I have an AWS Appsync API set up and I'm using Lambda resolvers to access a mongodb database. I want to be able to set cookie headers from the server side (lambda) and then pass it over to appsync which in turn sends it to the client. Is that even possible or do I have to find another workaround?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the exact setup but you can return any kind of data from AppSync such as a token (as long as its defined in your schema) then use your client (i.e. reactjs) to set a cookie using that info.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this in the end? I need to do the same.

Comment: @ctrlplusb I ended up using a client set cookie, less secure but got the job done.